# Can someone check my solution for the Record Collection exercise on freeCodeCamp?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here are the instructions.

Your function must always return the entire record collection object.

If prop isn't tracks and value isn't an empty string, update or set that album's prop to value.

If prop is tracks but the album doesn't have a tracks property, create an empty array and add value to it.

If prop is tracks and value isn't an empty string, add value to the end of the album's existing tracks array.

If value is an empty string, delete the given prop property from the album.
Note: A copy of the recordCollection object is used for the tests.

My solution was:

```
function updateRecords(records, id, prop, value) {
  return records;
  if (prop !== "tracks" && value !== "") {
    records[id][prop] = value;
  } else if (prop == "tracks" && records[id].hasOwnProperty("tracks") == false) {
    records[id][prop] = [value];
  } else if (prop == "tracks" && value !== "") {
    records[id][prop].push(value);
  } else if (value == "") {
    delete records[id][prop];
  }
  return records;
}

updateRecords(recordCollection, 5439, 'artist', 'ABBA');
```

Why didn't this work?

Comment: you have a return statement at the very top of your function (presumeably - its not formatted correctly here).

Comment: And if it is not tippler, return is basically exit from the function. And you have it very start of it...

Comment: Also always create a  [mre] , you posted a task without data to test it. we are not mind readers.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to this [task](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/record-collection)

```js
const recordCollection={2548:{albumTitle:"Slippery When Wet",artist:"Bon Jovi",tracks:["Let It Rock","You Give Love a Bad Name"]},2468:{albumTitle:"1999",artist:"Prince",tracks:["1999","Little Red Corvette"]},1245:{artist:"Robert Palmer",tracks:[]},5439:{albumTitle:"ABBA Gold"}};

function updateRecords(records, id, prop, value) {
  const record = records[id];

  if (!value) {
    delete record[prop];
    return records;
  }

  if (prop === 'tracks') {    
    record[prop] ??= [];
    record[prop].push(value);
    return records;
  } 

  record[prop] = value;
  return records;
};

console.log(updateRecords(recordCollection, 5439, 'artist', 'ABBA')[5439]);
console.log(updateRecords(recordCollection, 5439, "tracks", "Take a Chance on Me")[5439]);
console.log(updateRecords(recordCollection, 2548, "artist", "")[2548])
console.log(updateRecords(recordCollection, 1245, "tracks", "Addicted to Love")[1245])
console.log(updateRecords(recordCollection, 2548, "tracks", "")[2548])
console.log(updateRecords(recordCollection, 1245, "albumTitle", "Riptide")[1245])
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

the way to do that:
first create significant records for testing.

PS: using [Logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) greatly simplifies the code.

```js
const
  rec0 = { 5439 : { prop1: "aaa" } }
, rec1 = { 5439 : { prop1: "aaa", artist: 'xyz' }  }
, rec2 = { 5439 : { prop1: "aaa", artist: 'xyz' }  }
, rec3 = { 5439 : { prop1: "aaa"                           }}
, rec4 = { 5439 : { prop1: "aaa", tracks: ['aa','bb','cc'] }}
, rec5 = { 5439 : { prop1: "aaa", tracks: ['aa','bb','cc'] }}
;

console.log( JSON.stringify( updateRecords( rec0,  5439, 'artist', 'ABBA' )))
console.log( JSON.stringify( updateRecords( rec1,  5439, 'artist', 'ABBA' )))
console.log( JSON.stringify( updateRecords( rec2,  5439, 'artist', ''     )))

console.log( JSON.stringify( updateRecords( rec3,  5439, 'tracks', 't1' )))
console.log( JSON.stringify( updateRecords( rec4,  5439, 'tracks', 't1' )))
console.log( JSON.stringify( updateRecords( rec5,  5439, 'tracks', ''   )))


function updateRecords(records, id, prop, value)
  {
  if (prop == 'tracks')
    {
    records[id].tracks ??= [];
    if (value.length)  records[id].tracks.push(value);
    else        delete records[id].tracks;
    }
  else if (value.length) 
    records[id][prop] = value;

  return records;
  }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```